# QWizard and forms for each QWizardPage

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I'm writing an application in Qt for my university project. As my main widget I chose QWizard. I decided to make a form (ui file) for each of the QWizardPage that will be in the wizard. I added the pages to QWizard, everything worked smoothly. However, my WizardPages need to pass variables between themselves and even though I've been trying to do this trying everything I could think of, I did not find a solution. Is there an easy way to do it? I suppose it might've been a little easier to accomplish If I hadn't used QtDesigner, but I'd really preffer to avoid rewriting the UI.

To make things clear, what I got is: QWizard main widget with own UI form, pages are promoted in QtDesigner to my own classes. Each class has it's own UI form. To set up the UI I call `ui->setup(this)` in the constructor of my QWizard. The problem I'm struggling with is passing variables between the pages.

Comment: this is a design issue, there is quite a few ways to do this. Can you post your code ( one of your poperty page classes , and where the function where the property page is added to the wizzard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Therefore you could use [QWizard's field mechanism](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#registering-and-using-fields).